# Set RGB color from a value in a cell in Excel

Tags: vba, excel, colors, rgb

I have a macro which draw bunch of charts for me.
What I'd like to do is dynamically change `color` of `Data series`. I use `RGB` color palete and function `.ForeColor.RGB`.
When I use it directly `.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(88, 88, 88)` - everything works fine. But When I try to take `color` from a `cell` `.ForeColor.RGB = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)` I got an error `Type missmatch`.
In `Cell(1,1)` I have value: `RGB(0, 0, 0)`.

How to pick `color` for `Data series` from `cell`?

Macro and Excel window below.

```
Sub Macro1()

ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart 1").Activate
ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Select

MsgBox Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)

With Selection.Format.Fill
    .Visible = msoTrue
    .ForeColor.RGB = Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1)
    '.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(88, 88, 88)
    .Transparency = 0
    .Solid
End With

End Sub
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't pass function name as a `String` value. `RGB()` is a `Function`

Try this. This will take values from 3 different cells say D4,E4 and F4.

```
.ForeColor.RGB = RGB( _
                     Sheets(1).Cells(4, 4), _
                     Sheets(1).Cells(4, 5), _
                     Sheets(1).Cells(4, 6) _
                     )
```

Comment: Way1 looks more convenient, however it leads to an error: `Argument not optional`.
Way2 works fine!

Comment: Yeah my fault. Apologies. Updated the post

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
'/* have to add this line */
ret = Split(Replace(Replace(Sheets(1).Cells(1, 1), "RGB(", ""), ")", ""), ",")
.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(ret(0),ret(1),ret(2))
```

Comment: ++ another nice approach :)